# how to switch language in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-5.7

I'm new to the this forum and this is my first question. I am developing an laravel application.so that application default language is **`English`**. I want to change this in to **`Chinese`**.

My requirement is main language is  **`Chinese`** and other language is **`English`**. My language chooser is working fine, but when i change app "local" to Chinese but it's change. I tried clear cache and recheck it same thing.not change language. I have already created two language array "en" for English "ch" for Chinese.

**config/app.php**

```
'locale' => 'en',  

'fallback_locale' => 'ch',
```

**LanguageMiddleware** `app/Http/Middleware`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if(Session::has('locale')){
        app()->setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**web.php** `routes/web.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'language'],function(){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this one

You can change the active language at runtime using the `setLocale` method on the App facade

```
App::setLocale($locale);     //by facade.
app()->setLocate($locate);   ///by helper
```

You may use the `getLocale` and `isLocale` methods  to determine the current locale or check if the locale is a given value

```
$locale = App::getLocale();   //get current language

if (App::isLocale('en')) {  //if current language is english then true else false.
    //
}
```

> You can als configure a "fallback language", which will be used when the
>   active language does not contain a given translation string

```
'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

for more information read this [article](https://learninglaravel.net/detect-and-change-language-on-the-fly-with-laravel) and [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#introduction) laravel official document

Answer (score 0):

Some packages may ship with their own language files. Instead of changing the package's core files to tweak these lines, you may override them by placing files in the  `resources/lang/vendor/{package}/{locale}` directory.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization

I think this package help you to switch language

https://github.com/akaunting/language

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, the locale was changing in session but not in config.
So have checked the session's locale in every blade and controller and set the default the language instant from there, here is the code on my blade file

```php
    if(\Session::get('locale') == 'en') \App::setLocale('en');
    else                                \App::setLocale('bn');
```

Hope it will help you